# How to render by material in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I wanna ask how to render an object per material, So i.e I want to render only an object with the same material(pink) and then in the other layer it will be another object also in the same material(Blue). So it will be 2 different render image output, pink object and blue object.
How do I do that. Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by: "So it will be 2 different render image output, pink object and blue object"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask sounds pretty close to *Cryptomatte* in the *Compositor*. First go into the *Layer* panel and under *Cryptomatte* activate *Material*:

[image]

In the *Render panel > Film* > enable *Transparent*:

[image]

Do a render, open the *Compositor*, enable the *Nodes* and *Background* options (you should see your render as background, press <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to zoom in and out), create an *Output > Viewer* node, create 2 *Matte > Cryptomatte* nodes, mix the 2 Cryptomatte with a *Color > Alpha* Over, click on the "+" button of the *Cryptomatte* node in order to pick up one object, click on the "+" button of the other *Cryptomatte* node in order to pick up the other object, you can assign a different effect to each layer:

[image]

You can visualize the mask of each *Cryptomatte* with the *Matte* output:

[image]